# Where are Windows Sidebar gadgets installed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, sidebar

I'm switching to a new computer and want to copy over the Vista/Win7 Sidebar gadgets I've downloaded to the new machine.

Where are those copied when I install them from the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets
```